# Question about For loops in python Confusion in nested loops

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

Alright so i am new at python and got little bit confused about one number that i can not understand where it came from and the number is 2, i understood why and how other numbers got looped and increased but i just can't understand where 2 came from.

This is code :

```
for a in range(5):
    print(i)
    for i in range(3):
        print(a)
```

This is the output.

```
2
0
0
0
2
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
2
4
4
4
```

i tried to print in (i,end=" ") (a,end=" ") way aswell 2 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 4 4 4
to understand it more i tried this --> print(i,end=" | ") 2 | 0 0 0 2 | 1 1 1 2 | 2 2 2 2 | 3 3 3 2 | 4 4 4

Which got me confused even more so if anyone can tell me where does this starting 2 come from or why 2 and why not 0 1 2 000 0 1 2 111 .... 0 1 2 444 like this and why 2

Comment: The starting `2` isn't coming from this code. You must have assigned `i` earlier in the program, and that's what it prints first.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is

```
a = 0
i = 0

for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    for a in range(3):
        print(a)
```

there is no way that 2 is getting printed first. Unless a or i start with 2 it would not print first. Is there a chance you have the variable defined somewhere else in the code? How you formatted your question makes it difficult to determine what is actually going on.

As just a small explanation into nested loops

```
for i in range(5)
```

I am assuming i is 0. It will print the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. The nested

```
for a in range(3)
```

will do the same, except it will happen 3x times since it is nested and it will only print 0,1,2

```
0,0,1,2, 1,0,1,2, 2,0,1,2, 3,0,1,2, 4,0,1,2
```

Comment: Now that you posted an update and a is printed before i, it seems these variables are used somewhere else in the code. Make sure they are the values you expect before beginning the loop

Comment: @AkakiAkhobadze please upvote if any part of my comment gave you your answer :)

Comment: but can i ask like 0,0,1,2, 1,0,1,2, 2,0,1,2, 3,0,1,2, 4,0,1,2 we got these numbers right why is it 4 numbers instead of 5

Comment: @AkakiAkhobadze the upper bound of a python loop is exclusive. So with range(5) you are getting 5 numbers starting at 0. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: i tested your code and i think your code and mine gives different results check this out 
for a in range(5):
    print(i,end=" ")
    for i in range(3):
        print(a,end=" ") thats why 2 confused me

Comment: yeah my code will give a different result because the print(i) and print(a) are swapped. Your expected result is - 
(0000) (2111) (2222) (2333) (2444) I broke thoes up into top loop iterations. a starts as 0, which is why the first value is always 0. The next 3 loops begin with 2 because the interior loop is being iterated (and not printed) so python is doing (0,1,2) so a will be 2 when it is printed in the top layer. i is only getting iterated on the outside which is why we see the 000 111 222 333 444

Answer (score 1):

```
for a in range(5):
    print(i)
    for i in range(3):
        print(a)
```

In this code, as you said you understand where other numbers come from i.e. `a`.
So when the `for i in range(3)` is running, it is first `0`, then `1` and finally `2`.
`i` is a variable that remains `2` unless it's value is changed.
As a result, it prints `2` in the next iteration. The value of `i` remains `2` until the next time `for i in range(3)` is run. In this loop, only one command is there i.e. `print(a)`. Therefore, it prints `2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1` and so on...

Comment: Yes you are right i tried to print(i) even after the loop and it just gives the number 2 even if i put print(i) after i loop but behind it it will do the same but in reverse so it starts from the end with 2 so its still confusing that why it is not changing and why it is fixed to number two but yes at least i found out where it came from ty so much